# How to solve Error: validation: chart.metadata is required on Mac using microk8s

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kubectl, microk8s, multipass

I have installed microk8s on Mac. I want to deploy an application using helm3 but it complains that `Error: validation: chart.metadata is required`. I am running this in the same directory as `Chart.yaml` as shown below.

```
➜  gluu git:(4.1) ✗ ls 
Chart.yaml  charts      templates   values.yaml
```

Here is the command

```
➜  gluu git:(4.1) ✗ helm3 install zz .   
Error: validation: chart.metadata is required
An error occurred when trying to execute 'sudo microk8s.helm3 install zz .' with 'multipass': returned exit code 1.
```

I am aliases for microk8s commands. Both `Helm3` and `kubectl`

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by running this command.
`multipass exec MicroK8sVM -- sudo /snap/bin/microk8s.config > $HOME/.kube/config`

The problem was, `microk8s helm3 install` was looking for the `Chart.yaml` in the vm created by multipass.